# Make some items of Nestedlist unclickable in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I have a nestedlist filled with items. I want to make some of the items unclickable. Is there a variable to unset or some kind of flag I can set?

UPDATE. Under items I mean the data loaded from Store object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple. I have just override basic function `onItemTap` of my nestedlist and base my function on code from basic function. Than I have implemented some needed logic and that's it.

```
onItemTap: function(list, index, target, record, e) {
    var me = this,
    store = list.getStore(),
    node = store.getAt(index);

    var is_separator = record.get('separator');

    me.fireEvent('itemtap', this, list, index, target, record, e);
    if (node.isLeaf()) {
        if (! is_separator) {
            me.fireEvent('leafitemtap', this, list, index, target, record, e);
            me.goToLeaf(node);
        }
    } else {
        if (! is_separator) {
            this.goToNode(node);
        }
    }
}
```